# PHP: Using regex to create string

Tags: php

Is there any way to use a regex expression to create a string, instead of just finding if a match exists?

I have a function to create a random string of characters:

```
public function getRandomString($length=8) {

  $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $string = '';

  for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
  }

  return $string;

} // End
```

I was wondering if there was any way to use a regex expression like `/[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of typing out all the characters...?

Comment: You will certainly look for `range()`.

Comment: Not a regex, but have a look for [range()](https://secure.php.net/range)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `range()`:

```
$letters = range('0', 'Z');
```

Comment: When I replace the above function `$characters` string with your `range` example, it's not working because `range` creates an array.